# Html Email, Allow Customers to Change Email Text

Tags: html, html-email

Im looking for a solution to a relatively simple problem. Currently our designer builds email designs in photoshop. I then get sent all the files. However sometimes we need to allow the clients to forward and edit the price on email. the designer send me the files in html with the images just being referenced via

```
<img src="imageURL"/>
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you talking about changing the email from distribution to distribution not once it's been sent? Are the images sent as part of the email or held on a server somewhere?

Comment: The image are just referenced. So I get an email with the layout, and theres a cellphone and the price is $100.00. I want that value field to be editable to allow our clients to forward it and change it to $150.00.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you sending the emails? If you use an ESP like Campaign Monitor or Mailchimp, they have a template language, where you can insert simple tags into the html to easily empower clients to edit sections. Example [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/create/).

You mentioned using images, if you change any image that is being referenced, that is also an easy way to update the email. The email html doesn't know what the image looks like, so if `myimage.jpg` has $100 on it now, but you change it to $150 before sending, it will show $150. This is bad practice however as all critical information in your email should never be in images - they are blocked by default in most email clients.

On a side note, your email designer should be hand coding your emails, NOT building them in Photoshop. Photoshop is fine for a mock up, but if they are using slices or trying to export html from there, it will break across email clients. Your email should also not be mostly images. This affects your deliverability, and as mentioned above, they will not load by default in most email clients, lowering the effectiveness of your campaign.